# MySQL exists making query take too long

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm very new to MySQL and right now I'm trying to make the following select:

```
SELECT
        a.qtd,
        a.value
    FROM
        order_products a,
        products b,
        orders c
    WHERE
        b.id = a.product_id
        and a.order_id = c.id
        and c.status = '2'
        and c.seller_id = '$result->seller_id'
        and exists(select id from dealer_products p where p.product_id = b.id and p.id_dealer = '$dealer')
```

This query is taking around 58 seconds using `LIMIT '1'`, without it I don't even get a response.

Removing the `and exists(select id from dealer_products p where p.product_id = b.id and p.id_dealer = '$dealer')` makes the response time drop to 0.78 seconds to return the same 1 result.

This is what I get when using `EXPLAIN` on the select:
[image]

Is there a way to improve this query so it won't take this ridiculous amount of time?

Comment: In addition to the explain, questions about query performance generally require CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exists(select id from dealer_products p where p.product_id = b.id and p.id_dealer = '$dealer')
```

instead of that you can use

```
b.id in (select id from dealer_products p where p.product_id = b.id and p.id_dealer = '$dealer')
```

Comment: @Rafael could you please mark this as answer. If it helped you.  :)

Comment: In some MySQL versions, the `IN` version runs a lot slower.

Comment: Not sure in this case (since there's no test data to work with) but `IN` tends to perform slower than `EXISTS` because `EXISTS` returns true on the first match, whereas `IN` has to generate a set and then check against it before it can return true. Maybe MySQL has improved since being bought out by Oracle, not sure, but I know a lot of older versions of *SQL (e.g. MSSQL 2005, 2008, 2008R2) would generate better execution plans for `EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

DEarTh's answer pointed me in the right direction.

Still using `b.id in (select id from dealer_products p where p.product_id = b.id and p.id_dealer = '$dealer')` was't returning the correct value.

To fix it I've changed it to `b.id in (select product_id from dealer_products where dealer_id = '$dealer')`. Worked just fine, response time 0.012 seconds.

Comment: How does it compare with a regular join

Comment: `from product_id from dealer_products` - that shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `JOIN ... ON` syntax:

```
SELECT  ...
    FROM  orders         AS o
    JOIN  order_products AS op  ON op.order_id = o.id
    JOIN  products       AS  p  ON p.id = op.product_id
    WHERE  o.status = 2
      AND  o.seller_id = '...'
      AND  EXISTS(
               SELECT  *    -- Note: no need for `id`
                   FROM  dealer_products
                   WHERE  product_id = p.id
                     AND  id_dealer = '...' 
                 )
```

Indexes needed:

```
orders:  INDEX(status, seller_id, id) -- in either order
order_products:  INDEX(order_id, product_id)  -- "covering"
products:  INDEX(id)  -- but not if it is already PRIMARY KEY(id)
dealer_products: INDEX(id_dealer, product_id) -- note slight change in subquery
```

Also, follow the tips in [*Many:Many mapping tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .